# Parse server cloud async function not returning the result

Tags: javascript, android, async-await, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I have an async function which should return `true` or `false` but it's been executed several times according to the logs instead of once and end but returning an `i/o failure` error message instead of the expected value.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("updateMatch", async (request) => {
    const query = new Parse.Query("Match");
    query.equalTo("league", request.params.league);
    const results = await query.find();

    var match = null;
    if (results.length > 0) {
        match = results[0];
    }else{
          var Match = Parse.Object.extend("Match");
            match = new Match();
            match.set("groupId", request.params.Id);
    }
     match.set("stadium",request.params.stadium);
     var saved = await match.save(null, { useMasterKey: true });
    return true;
});
```

When i changes the async function to a normal function, it get executed once and returns the expected value which is `true`

```
 Parse.Cloud.define("updateMatch", function(request,response){
        const query = new Parse.Query("Match");
        query.equalTo("league", request.params.league);
        query.find().then((results)=>{
         var match = null;
        if (results.length > 0) {
            match = results[0];
        }else{
              var Match = Parse.Object.extend("Match");
                match = new Match();
                match.set("groupId", request.params.Id);
        }
         match.set("stadium",request.params.stadium);
         match.save(null, { useMasterKey: true });
        return response.success(true);
        });
    });
```

This is the way I'm calling the function from android

```
val params = HashMap<String, Any>()
    params["league"] = "EPA"
    params["groupId"] = "A"
    params["stadium"] = "Etihad"

    ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("updateMatch", params,FunctionCallback { success, e ->
       AppLogger.error("success? ${success} error is ${e?.message}")

      }
```

What could be the problem with the async function?

Comment: Can you please take a look in this line here? (val saved = await match.save(null, { useMasterKey: true });) It should be "var" right? Also, what is the parse version you are using? Do you see something in your logs?

Comment: marking that function `async` will mean it returns a *`Promise`* - in this case, the Promise will resolve to `true` once the function completes  ... perhaps whatever `ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground` is (doesn't look at all javascript) doesn't understand what to do with a Promise

Comment: Also, your "async" version only takes one argument, and the working one takes two ... yet you're calling it with the same code ... that makes no sense at all ... how do you call the working function *"from android"*

Comment: @JaromandaX I call the working function the same way i call the async function. See the android code at the bottom of the question. Please note that this is one function. i had written it as an async function, it never returned result and i changed it to a normal function which returned the result.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo i have changed val to var. it was a typo error. My parse-server version is `2.8.2`

Comment: exactly @EdijaeCrusar - yet the two functions take a different number of arguments ... how can it ever work for both?

Comment: @JaromandaX I was following the parse cloud code tutorial on how to write the async fucntion. [https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#cloud-functions](https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#cloud-functions)

Comment: Can you please try to update parse server to the latest version and test again? Promised Cloud Functions are only available in versions above 3.0.

Comment: Your code doesn't look like any of the examples in that page as far as I can see

Comment: @DaviMacêdo I updated my parse server to 3.3.0 and the async function worked.

Comment: @JaromandaX. When i updated the parse-server to 3.3.0, it worked

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to implement async functions in parse-server version `2.8.2` which failed but when i updated to the latest version, my async functions now return the expected results.

To update all outdated modules including parse-server to the latest versions, the command below can be used. `-g` means global modules. it can be omitted to only update outdated local modules

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates && ncu -u && npm i
```